# Firebase using listeners vs full query

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I want to show list of customers (sorted by name and show only first 10) when my app opens. Which of the following ways efficient when using with firestore?

Approach1: When the app loads query for top 10 customers.
This will count as 10 doc reads by firestore. Correct?

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await fireStore
          .collection('customers')
          .orderBy('fname')
          .limit(documentLimit)
          .getDocuments();
```

Approach2: Set up a listener

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await fireStore
          .collection('customers')
          .orderBy('fname')
          .limit(documentLimit)
          .snapshots()
          .listen(someListener)
```

- Now if am using firestore will the above pattern will be efficient in terms of number of reads?
- Does firestore cache documents on client side between application runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Both samples show 10 initial documents reads.  There is nothing "inefficient" about any query in Firestore that will be satisfied by the server.  What you're showing now is just different in that the first one will query an single time, and the second one will receive results continually as they change, with each new document costing another read.  Use the options that meets your needs.  If you don't need realtime update, them don't add a listener.  Maybe [this video](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/enable-offline) will help you decide which you really need.
2. Yes, for Android, iOS, and web apps.  [Read the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/enable-offline) about it.

Comment: That helped. But how do i conver from json as string to Customer? With the above lib i got following method : _$CustomerFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json). But i have json as string.

Comment: It sounds like you now have a second question that's not related to the efficient or behavior of the request.  Could you post it as a separate question, showing the complete code that's not working the way you expect?

Comment: i found a way.Thanks